# It doesnt show the captured image after captured. It means _storeImage still null after we captured

Tags: flutter, dart

It doesnt show the captured image after captured.
It means   _storeImage still null after we captured .
basically this code is for widget as named as ImageInput.
I also added the screenshot of the app.
still after capture image the box shows "No image Taken"

```
 import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageInput({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageInput> createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  File? _storeImage = null;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final XFile? imageFile =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxWidth: 600);
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    setState() {
      // TODO: implement setState
      _storeImage = File(imageFile.path);
     
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
          child: _storeImage != null
              // ignore: dead_code
              ? Image.file(
                  _storeImage!,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: double.infinity,
                )
              : Text(
                  'No image Taken',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TextButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
          label: Text('Takeb A Photo'),
          onPressed: _takePicture,
        )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setState` wrong, try this:

```
setState(() {
   _storeImage = File(imageFile.path);
});
```